# calculating FDR threshold for FST and PBS statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, false-discovery-rate

I have fixation index statistics (FST) for approximately 4 million loci, genome-wide. I would like to calculate a 5% FDR threshold in order to select the top loci in terms of highest FST statistics. Population genetics papers often take the top x% FDR for FST and PBS stats, but do not state in methods how they calculate the FDR threshold.

I have tried calculating P-values, then calculating q values using fdrtool in R, but these FDR thresholds seem to be falling very low (not stringent at all). Can someone explain what it means to take a top x% FDR?

An example of a paper that uses FDR cutoff here (in figure 1):

Whole genome sequencing of Ethiopian highlanders reveals conserved hypoxia tolerance genes
Udpa et. al. 2014
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4054780/

Comment: Thanks, I saw the paper. That 0.1% FDR is a new $\alpha$ value they calculated to account for the number of tests they are performing, similar to what I described below. This is not 1% of tests, but rather the P value cut off that controls the FDR to 1%. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a slight misunderstanding as to what controlling the FDR entails. I'm not familiar with FST statistics, but I've done several genome wide association studies and similar, and I'm confident that it works the same way.

When a paper says (and perhaps you could link us to the paper you're looking at so we can confirm) that they have controlled the FDR to 5%, that **doesn't mean** that they have adjusted all of their $p$-values and then subsequently taken the top 5% of these results. That is not controlling the FDR in any meaningful way.

In a typical statistical test you have an $\alpha$ value which is typically set to either 0.01 or 0.05. If a P value falls below this alpha value then you declare the ratio of signal to noise "significant". I'm sure you've read about this, but as you increase the number of tests that you are performing, you (almost) guarantee that you will get false positives just because of the number of tests you are performing. When you FDR adjust your $P$ values, you are (basically) looking to set a new $\alpha$ which controls the proportion of false positives to all positives i.e. $$ FDR = \left( \frac{E[V]}{E[V] + E[S]} \right) $$ Where $V$ is tests which are declared significant, but in truth are not, and S is tests which are declared significant and are actually significant. **This is the quantity which we would like to limit to 5%** rather than taking the top 5% of $P$-values, which does nothing in fact to control any inflation.

So, as you are doing this in `R`, you can do a few things going forward. You should look at the [`qvalue`](https://github.com/StoreyLab/qvalue) package released by John Storey and also the base `p.adj` method in `R`. The associated paper is also helpful. [1]

As a quick demonstration of what I mean:

```r
library(qvalue)
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)

z_null <- list()
z_true <- list()
p_null <- vector()
p_true <- vector()

foreach(n = 1:1000) %do% {
    z_null[[n]] <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
    z_true[[n]] <- rnorm(100, 1, 1)
    p_null[n] <- t.test(z_null[[n]], mu = 0)$p.value
        p_true[n] <- t.test(z_true[[n]], mu = 0)$p.value

}

p <- rbind(p_true, p_null)
length(p[p < 0.05]) # this gives 56 false positives on one run

p.adj <- p.adjust(p, method = "BH")
length(p.adj[p.adj < 0.05]) # after adjustment there are only 29 false positives
```

If you had taken just the top 5% of P values, you would have missed a lot of truly associated variants.

**References**

1. Storey, J. D. [A direct approach to false discovery rates](http://www.genomine.org/papers/directfdr.pdf). J. R. Stat. B (2002).

Comment: +1 but do you mean this paper http://www.genomine.org/papers/directfdr.pdf ? It says 2002, not 1995.

Comment: @amoeba Whoops, yea thanks! Copied the first result for Storey from my reference manager.

Comment: I was not familiar with the Storey's paper but now see that it has thousands of citations and seems to claim (already in the abstract) to surpass the more standard Benjamini-Hochberg procedure. Is it really the case, what is the general opinion in the field? Storey's approach replaced BH one?

Comment: @amoeba That's a really good question, I'm not really sure. I'm really interested though so I'm going to take a closer read of that paper and perhaps put a question / answer up sometime this week because it seems like a really important distinction. To be honest I never saw that line before and it doesnt really make sense to me why it would be the case. I'll ping you in chat when I write it up :)

Comment: I can also post this question myself, if you prefer. Or ping in me chat when you are ready to answer and I will ask :-) I would then ask about what are the differences between Storey and BH and is it true that Storey outperforms BH.

Comment: @amoeba Sounds fun! Maybe some others will chime in with things that I may miss. If it's true then I don't think it's a commonly known thing (at least, no one I've ever talked to has mentioned it). Anyway, I'll look into it and ping you when I'm more knowledgable. Have a good one! :)

Comment: Hmm, but why are you recommending this paper and this qvalue package (e.g. in this answer) as opposed to the Benjamini-Hochberg paper?

Comment: @amoeba Estimating the point FDR value (ie the q value) as opposed to the stepwise procedure in BH allows for more interpretable results for people used to the $\alpha =0.05$ convention to attempt to reject the null. It was always my understanding that the $q$ value approach simply gave a point FDR value (ie the value of FDR control that would be required to reject the null at that particular threshold) and that was it, but I think I was incorrect and that the qvalue method actually does do more than that. So I was recommending it more out of convenience than for an increase in power.